MLKit Object Detection Can't detect and Can't draw the bounding box?
so basically I'm learning on an app From the MLKit sample apps and others to detect an object with MLKit object detection and draw boundingBox with a custom, view. At first, I does work and I can detect the object and draw the boundingBox, but yet I forget to commit the project and just modified my code then it was can't detect the object, I just wondering what's going on
Here's my 4 code that I potentially focus on the problem on

ScanFragment (Here's the portion of the Fragment code)

private fun startCamera() {
        binding.cameraPreviewGraphicOverlay.clear()
        val rotation = binding.previewView.display.rotation

        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build()

        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            preview = Preview.Builder()
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                .build()

            preview?.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)

            imageAnalyser = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                .build()
                .apply {
                    setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) {
                        ObjectDetectorProcessor(multiObjectMode) { it1, it2 ->
                            createOverlay(it1, it2)
                        }
                    }
                }


            cameraProvider.unbindAll()
            try {
                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this,
                    cameraSelector,
                    preview,
                    imageAnalyser
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", e)
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
    }

    private fun createOverlay(objectList: MutableList<DetectedObject>, rect: Rect) {
        binding.cameraPreviewGraphicOverlay.clear()
        objectList.forEach { detectedObject ->
            val overlayView = ObjectDetectorGraphic(binding.cameraPreviewGraphicOverlay, detectedObject, rect)
            binding.cameraPreviewGraphicOverlay.add(overlayView)
        }
    }

}


ObjectDetectorProcessor

class ObjectDetectorProcessor(
    private val listener: (MutableList<DetectedObject>, image: Rect) -> Unit
) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    private val options = ObjectDetectorOptions.Builder()
        .apply {
            setDetectorMode(ObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
        }.build()

    private val detector = ObjectDetection.getClient(options)
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image ?: kotlin.run {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: imageProxy null")
            imageProxy.close()
            return
        }

        val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
        detector.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener {objectList ->
                listener(objectList, image.mediaImage?.cropRect!!)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: ${it.message}", it)
            }
    }
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "ObjectAnalyser"
    }
}


GraphicOverlay (as the custom View)

class GraphicOverlay(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {

    private val lock = Any()
    var mScale: Float? = null
    var mOffsetX: Float? = null
    var mOffsetY: Float? = null
    private val graphics = ArrayList<Graphics>()

    /**
     * Base class for a custom graphics objects to be rendered within the graphic overlay.
     * The subclass of this can implement the [Graphic.draw] method to define the graphics element,
     * and to add the instances of graphic to the overlay using the [GraphicOverlay.add]
     * */
    abstract class Graphics protected constructor(protected val overlay: GraphicOverlay) {
        protected val context: Context = overlay.context

        /** Draws the graphic on the supplied canvas. */
        abstract fun draw(canvas: Canvas)

        fun calculateRect(height: Float, width: Float, boundingBoxT: Rect): RectF {

            // for land scape
            fun isLandScapeMode(): Boolean {
                return overlay.context.resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            }

            fun whenLandScapeModeWidth(): Float {
                return when(isLandScapeMode()) {
                    true -> width
                    false -> height
                }
            }

            fun whenLandScapeModeHeight(): Float {
                return when(isLandScapeMode()) {
                    true -> height
                    false -> width
                }
            }

            val scaleX = overlay.width.toFloat() / whenLandScapeModeWidth()
            val scaleY = overlay.height.toFloat() / whenLandScapeModeHeight()
            val scale = scaleX.coerceAtLeast(scaleY)
            overlay.mScale = scale

            // Calculate offset (we need to center the overlay on the target)
            val offsetX = (overlay.width.toFloat() - ceil(whenLandScapeModeWidth() * scale)) / 2.0f
            val offsetY = (overlay.height.toFloat() - ceil(whenLandScapeModeHeight() * scale)) / 2.0f

            overlay.mOffsetX = offsetX
            overlay.mOffsetY = offsetY

            val mappedBox = RectF().apply {
                left = boundingBoxT.right * scale + offsetX
                top = boundingBoxT.top * scale + offsetY
                right = boundingBoxT.left * scale + offsetX
                bottom = boundingBoxT.bottom * scale + offsetY
            }

            return mappedBox
        }
    }

    fun clear() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            graphics.clear()
        }
        postInvalidate()
    }

    fun add(graphic: Graphics) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            graphics.add(graphic)
        }
    }

    /** Draws the overlay with its associated graphic objects.  */
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        synchronized(lock) {
            graphics.forEach { it.draw(canvas) }
        }
    }

}


And lastly the ObjectDetectorGraphic

class ObjectDetectorGraphic(overlay: GraphicOverlay, private val detectedObject : DetectedObject, private val rect: Rect) : Graphics(overlay) {

    private val paintFill = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = Color.argb(70, 255, 255, 255)
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    private val paintStroke = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = Color.GRAY
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 3f
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
//        val rect = overlay.translateRect(detectedObject.boundingBox)
        val rect = calculateRect(
            rect.height().toFloat(),
            rect.width().toFloat(),
            detectedObject.boundingBox
        )
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paintFill)
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paintStroke)
    }
}

At this rate, I don't know what's wrong and yet don't know how to debug for that since on the logcat it seems I can't find anything useful for my case.
I'm already looking at this case
(MLKit Object Detection is not detecting objects), but still not found working

Silly me, I thought of something complex such as the dependencies version and etc, and the answer is really simple. It's just because the placement of the analyzer method within the setAnalyzer in the ImageAnalysis
setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) {
  ObjectDetectorProcessor(multiObjectMode) { it1, it2 ->
     createOverlay(it1, it2)
}

The setAnalyzer takes the executor and the analyzer and I thought I can put the analyzer inside the lambda function, so the correct answer must be like this
setAnalyzer(
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), 
    ObjectDetectorProcessor(multiObjectMode) { it1, it2 ->
        createOverlay(it1, it2)
    }
)

Have a great day
